# Spring NoSuchMethod Error on Apache Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, netbeans

I'm trying to set up a Java Web Application to run on my local Tomcat server. I've made progress, but my current issue is that when I try to deploy to the server, I get the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SiteAdmin-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getResourceLoader()Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;
```

After some time with Google, I came to understand that this a dependency issue of some sort. Here are the Spring dependencies I'm currently using

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId> 
                <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>        
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>  
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                 <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
             <!--<version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>-->
           </dependency>
          
            <dependency>        
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId> 
                <version>2.5.5</version> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency>        
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> 
                <version>2.5.5</version>
            <!--<version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>-->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>        
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> 
                <version>2.5.5</version> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency>        
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId> 
                <version>2.5.5</version> 
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>        
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId> 
                <version>2.5.5</version> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency>        
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId> 
                <version>2.5.5</version> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency>        
                <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId> 
                <version>0.8a</version> 
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>    
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> 
                <version>2.5.5</version>    
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>    
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId> 
                <version>2.5.5</version> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency>    
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> 
                <version>2.5.5</version>        
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>    
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> 
                <version>2.5.5</version> 
            </dependency>
```

As can be seen above, I tried updating the spring-core and the spring-beans dependencies to later versions, but the error persists. I want to avoid changing the dependencies too much, since when I tried updating all of them it caused errors elsewhere in my code. Any help in how to approach this issue would be appreciated.

If it helps, I'm using Netbeans and Java 6. I want to avoid changing that Java version if I can.

Comment: [1] If possible, you really should upgrade from Java 6, because: (a) It's no longer supported. (b) There are security risks associated with using old unsupported Java versions. There haven't been any security updates for Java 6 since 2013! (c) [Tomcat 8.5 requires JRE 7 or newer](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). [2] Note that if you run Tomcat 8.5 from NetBeans it will use whatever JRE version is being used by NetBeans (i.e its _default platform_), so make sure you are running NetBeans with a JDK >= 7 for Tomcat 8.5 to work properly. You can still use Java 6 for your project(s).

Comment: @skomisa I setup the server to run with Java 7 JDK, so that's fine. As for the Java version I was expressly told to use Java 6, so I don't want to change the version beyond that

Comment: The dependencies in the group `org.springframework` should all have the same version (you should probably use `2.5.6.SEC01`, since your version of `spring-webflow` depend on it, cf. [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.webflow/spring-webflow/2.0.8.RELEASE)).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I tried changing the versions to 2.5.6.SEC01, but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: Did you also change the version of `spring-core`? This is the most probable culprit.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz yep, I tried both with and without spring-core, neither worked

Comment: [1] Since the spring-core `<dependency>` version in your question has changed from 4.0.3, can you update the dependencies list (and the error message if necessary) to reflect the current situation? It shouldn't be necessary to interpret the comments to understand the problem. [2] It's worth verifying that **$TOMCAT_HOME/lib** does not contain any unwanted/unexpected jars. It's unlikely, but that is a potential cause for your problem. [3] Are you building/deploying your code, and then running Tomcat within NetBeans, or is Tomcat running externally? [4] What version of NetBeans are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem guys. There was an old spring-core dependency jar in the classpath. I didn't notice it at first because it was only called spring.jar. Got rid of it, error's gone.